# raspi+ADC realtime plotting

Tags: real-time, tkinter

I recently succeeded in receiving ADC Data from ADS7851 through SPI communication. Now I'm working on plotting those voltage data and also fft of them. I've done some research, and found out that matplotlib and PyQt UI is too heavy and slow to plot 1.5MSPS of data coming in. Therefore I concluded using pylab and Tkinter is efficient for my purpose.

I've made a function "readADC", which returns single realtime voltage value. Inside Tkinter, readADC and pylab should run simultaneously. I'm afraid that plotting algorithm might slow down the clock speed, or even worse, ruin the fft pattern. 
What is the best approach to do this?

https://hardsoftlucid.wordpress.com/various-stuff/realtime-plotting/

above is the basic concept I intend, of which the realtime voltage passes through. FFT graph should be shown on sperate canvas widget.

I'll be very glad to receive any advice(approach/tools/codes). Thank you.

Comment: If your current working solution resembles the one in your [first question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/71245/spi-communication-with-ads7851) it would be nice for follow-up readers to know what made it working.

Comment: Oh, I did comment but I agree that I should state it clearly. It was solved by wiring Vref_out port voltage below the half of AVDD and also initializng and setting CS high after the call. Thanks

Comment: On a Pi2B using the standard Linux driver (and from Python as well) you are unlikely to get 20ksps, let alone 1.5Msps.  The question may be moot.

Comment: Can you please comment a link to it? If that's true, I need to start over from the very beginning..

Comment: There is a problem between what signify for you "real time", what (usually) for other people and what you really need.
Remember that our eyes (and brain) don't need more than 24 fps (oversemplified...)

Comment: what I'm trying to do is about NILM(non intrusive load monitoring) which needs to get smps(switched mode power supply) noise from appliances. those noises have frequencies higher than 50kHz(which means sampling rate must be at least twice higher). Using 1.5MHZ ADC and raspberry pi, I'm trying to analyze the voltage signal. 'Real Time' I mean is processing 1.5MHz of voltage data coming in. showing as fft can be a little slower, by storing thousands of voltage data in buffer and then plotting it.

Comment: To add some detail, what's important is receiving 1.5MSPS of voltage Data. Showing it to the graph can be little slower. But at the backend the data should be processed with required speed.